# How to interact with Telegraf using Go external plugin?

Tags: go, plugins, grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I have a dummy GO plugin, using that, i want send data to telegraf. But, i'm not able to find any way to send data from the plugin to telegraf.
this external Go plugin looks like below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type greeting string
type n int

func (g greeting) Greet() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        timer1 := time.NewTimer(2 * time.Second)
        <-timer1.C
        fmt.Println("value ", i)

        sum := 0
        sum += i * 100
        fmt.Println(sum)
    }

}

// exported
var Greeter greeting
```

And the main file looks like

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "plugin"
)

type Greeter interface {
    Greet()
}

func main() {

    var mod string

    mod = "./eng/eng.so"

    // load module
    // 1. open the so file to load the symbols
    plug, err := plugin.Open(mod)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // 2. look up a symbol (an exported function or variable)
    // in this case, variable Greeter
    symGreeter, err := plug.Lookup("Greeter")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // 3. Assert that loaded symbol is of a desired type
    // in this case interface type Greeter (defined above)
    var greeter Greeter
    greeter, ok := symGreeter.(Greeter)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("unexpected type from module symbol")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // 4. use the module
    greeter.Greet()


}
```

Can anyone help me find a way or a direction on how to make interaction between GO plugin and telegraf work. Any heads up is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Telegraf does not support the use of external plugins. 
An [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/1717) was made and closed regarding this requested feature.

If you were planning on writing code in Golang I would suggest creating a custom Telegraf plugin. Telegraf plugins do not use go external plugin package instead they are built with Telegraf itself. Your plugin must satisfy the specific interface based on the type of plugin you want to create. Based on your question I will assume that you desire to create an input plugin, Telegraf has [examples](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/c78045c13f8964489d963c32efae1349a66f1ba6/docs/INPUTS.md) for creating each type of plugin in their source code.